# Composition and Inverse functions

Tags: functions

Let $g$ and $f$ be two functions such that $g \circ f(x)=x$ whenever $x\in D(f)$ and $f \circ g(x)=x$ whenever $x\in D(g)$.

Prove that $g=f^{-1}$.

I don't know where to start. How do we prove that $f$ is bijective in the first place, for it to have an inverse?

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=f(y)$, then $g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=g\bigl(f(y)\bigr)$, which means that $f$ is injective.

And if $y$ belongs to the cointerdomain of $f$, then $x=f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)$. So, $f$ is surjective.

This proves that $f$ is bijective. Therefore, it has an inverse. Can you guess what $f^{-1}$ is?

Comment: Wait..assuming $f(x)=f(y)$ we have to prove that $x=y$ to show that $f$ is injective right?..I don't understand your answer..Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Isn't $g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=x$? And isn't $g\bigl(f(y)\bigr)=y$?

Comment: Oh..yeah! I missed that..

Comment: How do we prove that $g=f^{-1}$?

Comment: Isn't this the same thing as asserting that $g\circ f$ and $f\circ g$ are both the identity function, which is something that you are assuming from the start?

Comment: I don't understand..can you please provide the complete proof?

Comment: How do you define $f^{-1}$?

Comment: If $f$ is the set of ordered pairs of the form $(x,y)$, then $f^{-1}$ is defined to be the set of ordered pairs $(y,x)$..assuming of course that $x\in D(f)$ and $y\in R(f)$ and that $f$ is bijective..

Comment: Oh..okay..I get it now...Thanks a lot for making me think!!